# Auto refresh window to using python

Tags: python

I would like to make a program for make my window refresh every 10 min. i'm new to programming and currently exploring python technology

My machine is connected with pc based software which will test the product

The software tend to be freeze and system hang-- we need to restart the pc to solve this issue

idea:
I want to make a python program to auto run and keep click refresh button  every 10min

my idea is to keep window always ready to receive data

I just beginning to explore below code ( very simple)

```
import mouse


#left click
      mouse.click("right")
      mouse.wheel(-3)
      # right click
      mouse.click("left")
```

How do I access the "refresh" option on the right click?

is my idea in not particle?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "window". Are you referring to a website refresh? If so, you wouldn't use Python for that, you'd use Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, so I'm just guessing you are in a browser window and want to refresh the site (right?)

Using the `mouse` package to do so will be very hard, therefore I suggest you use the [`keyboard`-package](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api), which is even from the same author.

```py
import keyboard
keyboard.send("F5")
```

Comment: Sorry for unclear information. I want to keep desktop refresh by 10m interval while my custom machine software program is running. This just an idea and please advice if it is practical or not. i'm sorry , im very new to the programming